# Making R function recognize C function in same package?

Tags: c, r

I downloaded a .tgz file which contains R scripts in R/ and a single C file in src/.

An R function calls the C function in this way:

```
Mainfn<-function(x) {
  output <- matrix(nrow(x),ncol(x));
  output<-.C("myCfn",x=as.double(x),output=as.double(output),
             PACKAGE='mypackage')
  return(output)
}
```

In the C file, the function is defined this way `[...]` denotes a long series of computations.

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rmath.h>
#include <math.h>
/*----------------------------------------------------------*/
void myCfn(double *x,double *output){
  [...]
}
```

When I install the package with `R CMD INSTALL mypackage.tgz`, `Mainfun()` gives an error: `"myCfn" not available for .C() for package "mypackage"`. I wonder how I can make my function recognize this function defined in the C file?

Comment: Did you build the C code? .C won't load from source code -- it's going to be looking for compiled C code.

Comment: I would also have a look at the `inline` and `Rcpp` package. These make combining R and C/C++ quite easy.

Comment: @josiber I thought the R CMD INSTALL command will compile the C from source code.

Comment: @Paul If I were writing this from scratch myself, I would try that but as I mentioned it's a package I downloaded so that's not really an option for this application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My best guess: the package needs `useDynLib(<pkg_name>)` in its `NAMESPACE` file.